# How to add list of object to list of object again?

Tags: list, listview, arraylist

I have method and this method return list of object, for example

```
List<Schedule> listSch = new ArrayList<Schedule>();

public List A (List<Schedule> listSch) {
   return listSch;
}
```

I Want add the return to the list new of object. 
How to add to the list?

Comment: You mean that you want to add an object and return - doing both operations in one line of code or what?

Comment: No, i only want to add result the return to new list.

Comment: I really didn't undestrand it again. Maybe you can edit the question and show some examples.